# How to read a gzip netcdf file in python?

Tags: python, gzip, netcdf

I have a working python program that reads in a number of large netCDF files using the Dataset command from the netCDF4 module. Here is a snippet of the relevant parts:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import glob

infile_root = 'start_of_file_name_'

for infile in sorted(glob.iglob(infile_root + '*')):
   ncin = Dataset(infile,'r')
   ncin.close()
```

I want to modify this to read in netCDF files that are gzipped. The files themselves were gzipped after creation; they are not internally compressed (i.e., the files are *.nc.gz). If I were reading in gzipped text files, the command would be:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import glob
import gzip

infile_root = 'start_of_file_name_'

for infile in sorted(glob.iglob(infile_root + '*.gz')):
   f = gzip.open(infile, 'rb')
   file_content = f.read()
   f.close()
```

After googling around for maybe half an hour and reading through the netCDF4 documentation, the only way I can come up with to do this for netCDF files is:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import glob
import os

infile_root = 'start_of_file_name_'

for infile in sorted(glob.iglob(infile_root + '*.gz')):
   os.system('gzip -d ' + infile)
   ncin = Dataset(infile[:-3],'r')
   ncin.close()
   os.system('gzip ' + infile[:-3])
```

Is it possible to read gzip files with the Dataset command directly? Or without otherwise calling gzip through os?

Comment: The [Dataset docs](http://netcdf4-python.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/netCDF4.Dataset-class.html) don't specify anything about gz files, so I don't think it's supported.  I'm sure there's a way of gunzipping them from within Python without a `gzip` system call, but I don't know what it would be.  Why do you need it to be handled by Dataset?

Comment: I didn't want to make separate calls to unzip and then re-gzip the files. I also mostly want to avoid the system call.

Comment: `gzip.open` returns a file-like object that can be used for read-only access to the file - but it looks like netCDF4 doesn't support that. If it were me, I'd use the python gzip module to unzip to a temporary file and leave the original alone. If its something that needed to be done often, you could start maintaining a cache of the ones you've unzipped. If the files are modified, you'' need to unzip and rezip anyway, so what the heck.

Comment: @tdelaney - Thanks. Using the gzip module to unzip to temporary files is a great suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because NetCDF4-Python wraps the C NetCDF4 library, you're out of luck as far as using the gzip module to pass in a file-like object. The only option is, as suggested by @tdelaney, to use the gzip to extract to a temporary file.

If you happen to have any control over the *creation* of these files, NetCDF version 4 files support zlib compression internally, so that using gzip is superfluous. It might also be worth converting the files from version 3 to version 4 if you need to repeatedly process these files.

Answer (score 10):

Reading datasets from memory is supported since netCDF4-1.2.8 ([Changelog](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python/blob/master/Changelog)):

```
import netCDF4
import gzip

with gzip.open('test.nc.gz') as gz:
    with netCDF4.Dataset('dummy', mode='r', memory=gz.read()) as nc:
        print(nc.variables)
```

See the description of the `memory` parameter in the [`Dataset` documentation](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#netCDF4.Dataset.__init__).

Alternative solution using xarray:

```py
import xarray as xr

with gzip.open("test.nc.gz") as fp:
    ds = xr.open_dataset(fp)
```

Comment: This works great. I use xarray to handle netcdf files but I am not aware of how to use xarray for similar operation. So far, I have to add a single conversion to this workflow for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433812/simple-conversion-of-netcdf4-dataset-to-xarray-dataset

Comment: I've added an example using xarray

Comment: Thanks. This example is really useful.

Answer (score 4):

Since I just had to solve the same problem, here is a ready-made solution:

```
import gzip
import os
import shutil
import tempfile

import netCDF4

def open_netcdf(fname):
    if fname.endswith(".gz"):
        infile = gzip.open(fname, 'rb')
        tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
        shutil.copyfileobj(infile, tmp)
        infile.close()
        tmp.close()
        data = netCDF4.Dataset(tmp.name)
        os.unlink(tmp.name)
    else:
        data = netCDF4.Dataset(fname)
    return data
```