# I want to select data using ranges of longitudes and latitudes in a NetCDF4 file using Python on Windows. I can't even open the dataset with xarray

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-xarray, netcdf4

I hoped that converting it into a DataFrame would help. I had planned to use the between function on the resulting dataframe. But the conversion itself does not work, even with xarray. I have another reason to want to convert it into a DataFrame: using Panda statsmodels.

Since I am on Windows, I can't use nctoolkit.

```py
#imports
import requests
import netCDF4 as nc
import gzip
#
# Download the gzipped datafile from GISS and load it into a netCDF Dataset
GISTEMPfile = requests.get('https://data.giss.nasa.gov/pub/gistemp/gistemp250_GHCNv4.nc.gz')
ds = nc.Dataset("dummy_path", mode="r", memory=gzip.decompress(GISTEMPfile.content))
ds.variables
v = ds.variables['tempanomaly']
#
#from pandas import DataFrame
#df = DataFrame(ds)
#
import xarray as xr
temp = xr.open_dataset(ds)
df = temp.to_dataframe()
```

For some reason, I am going in circles...

Try with 'netcdf4' engine ->

```
temp = xr.open_dataset(ds, engine='netcdf4')
```

File "C:\Users\jean-\Desktop\WPy64-31050\python-3.10.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\api.py", line 495, in open_dataset
backend_ds = backend.open_dataset(

File "C:\Users\jean-\Desktop\WPy64-31050\python-3.10.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\netCDF4_.py", line 553, in open_dataset
store = NetCDF4DataStore.open(

File "C:\Users\jean-\Desktop\WPy64-31050\python-3.10.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\netCDF4_.py", line 355, in open
raise ValueError(

ValueError: can only read bytes or file-like objects with engine='scipy' or 'h5netcdf'

Try with 'h5netcdf' engine ->

```
temp = xr.open_dataset(ds, engine='h5netcdf')
```

File "C:\Users\jean-\Desktop\WPy64-31050\python-3.10.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\api.py", line 481, in open_dataset
backend = plugins.get_backend(engine)

File "C:\Users\jean-\Desktop\WPy64-31050\python-3.10.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\plugins.py", line 156, in get_backend
raise ValueError(

ValueError: unrecognized engine h5netcdf must be one of: ['netcdf4', 'scipy', 'store', 'zarr']

I tried again without specifying the engine after upgrading to WinPython 3.11.3.1, to no avail ->

temp = xr.open_dataset(ds)
Traceback (most recent call last):

Cell In[3], line 1
temp = xr.open_dataset(ds)

File ~\Desktop\WPy64-31131\python-3.11.3.amd64\Lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\api.py:509 in open_dataset
engine = plugins.guess_engine(filename_or_obj)

File ~\Desktop\WPy64-31131\python-3.11.3.amd64\Lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\plugins.py:197 in guess_engine
raise ValueError(error_msg)

ValueError: did not find a match in any of xarray's currently installed IO backends ['netcdf4', 'h5netcdf', 'scipy', 'zarr']. Consider explicitly selecting one of the installed engines via the `engine` parameter, or installing additional IO dependencies

Are there dependencies that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xarray supports range based selection using the `sel` method and the slice object. For example:

```
ds = xr.open_dataset(...)
ds_region = ds.sel(lon=slice(-85.0, -80.1), lat=slice(-10.0, 10.0))
```

Comment: For some reason, I am going in circles...

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to open my dataset using the first answer to this question ->
[Simple conversion of netCDF4.Dataset to xarray Dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433812/simple-conversion-of-netcdf4-dataset-to-xarray-dataset?rq=3)

Instead of using
'''python
temp = xr.open_dataset(ds, engine='netcdf4')
'''
, for instance, I used

'''python
temp = xr.open_dataset(xr.backends.NetCDF4DataStore(ds))
'''
, which I could then convert into a DataFrame after slicing it up using the first answer I got to my original question.